# windows phone toolkit time picker convert to military time

Tags: windows-phone-7

Im currently using the available toolkit for windows phone. By using the time picker, I want to change it to military time. But I dont know to customize it.

So I came up with creating my own time picker by using the LoopingSelector, but I dont know how will I implement it along with appbar, since this was only a popup.

What is the strategic way to recreate this timepicker along with appbar?

Comment: What do you mean by "along with appbar"? Which part of the appbar is involved with implementing and presenting a time picker? Typically, the actually picker part of the Time/Date/ListPicker is actually a separate page.

Comment: if it is in separate page, where they store selected item then bind in to textbox when it goes back to the mainpage?

Comment: i just said along with appbar coz i think that it was only a popup, not in separate page.

Comment: OK, I see. I've added an answer with some links for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the underlying type is still the same (`DateTime`), then I think that rather than creating a new `TimePicker`, you could just implement a custom picker page as described in [WP7 DatePicker and TimePicker in depth | API and Customization](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization) on WindowsPhoneGeek.com. Richard Griffin also has a [post that covers the same topic](http://blogs.xamlninja.com/blend/wp7-contrib-customising-the-datetime-picker) for `DatePicker`.